# GCC reports undefined reference to an existing symbol

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

This is my linking command line:

```
g++ -o verdox src/AIFactory.o src/AnimatedMesh.o src/BalanceStone.o src/Camera.o \
src/Card.o src/Caterpillar.o src/Character.o src/Collectable.o src/Concave.o \
src/Configuration.o src/Dynamic.o src/DynBall.o src/Enemy.o src/FixedLight.o \
src/FuzzyState.o src/Game.o src/GameInput.o src/GameUnit.o src/HUD.o src/Level.o \
src/LogicAttributes.o src/MainCharacter.o src/Main.o src/Menu.o src/MenuInput.o \
src/MeshStrider.o src/Object.o src/ObjectFactory.o src/OgreDebugDrawer.o \
src/OgreMusic.o src/OgreSoundEffect.o src/Projectile.o src/Scenery.o src/Shape.o \
src/SoftBody.o src/Trigger.o src/Utils.o src/Verdox.o src/Wasp.o src/World.o \
UFUG/libufug.a TinyXML/libtinyxml.a -L[...](lots of library dirs) \
-lboost_thread-mt -logg -lvorbis -lvorbisfile -lConvexDecomposition \
-lBulletSoftBody -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision -lLinearMath \
-lOgreMain -lpthread /usr/local/lib/OGRE/Plugin_OctreeZone.so \
/usr/local/lib/OGRE/Plugin_PCZSceneManager.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/OGRE \
-L/usr/local/lib -lOgreMain -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lCEGUIBase \
-L/usr/local/lib -lCEGUIOgreRenderer -lOgreMain -lpthread -lCEGUIBase -lsigc-2.0 \
-lopenal -lOIS
```

I know there are some repetitions, but I think it should do no harm, and I don't want to fight the build system before knowing what is wrong.

The problem is that I get a few undefined references:

```
src/Game.o: In function `Game':
/home/lucas/src/ufugames/verdox/src/Game.cpp:64: undefined reference to `Ogre::PCZPlugin::PCZPlugin()'
/home/lucas/src/ufugames/verdox/src/Game.cpp:64: undefined reference to `Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin::OctreeZonePlugin()'
src/Game.o: In function `~PCZPlugin':
/home/lucas/src/ufugames/ogre_src_v1-8-0/PlugIns/PCZSceneManager/include/OgrePCZPlugin.h:49: undefined reference to `vtable for Ogre::PCZPlugin'
src/Game.o: In function `~OctreeZonePlugin':
/home/lucas/src/ufugames/ogre_src_v1-8-0/PlugIns/OctreeZone/include/OgreOctreeZonePlugin.h:47: undefined reference to `vtable for Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But all the symbols reported missing are found inside `Plugin_OctreeZone.so` and `Plugin_PCZSceneManager.so`:

```
$ nm -C /usr/local/lib/OGRE/Plugin_PCZSceneManager.so | grep "Ogre::PCZPlugin::PCZPlugin()"
00029440 t Ogre::PCZPlugin::PCZPlugin()
00029440 t Ogre::PCZPlugin::PCZPlugin()

$ nm -C /usr/local/lib/OGRE/Plugin_PCZSceneManager.so | grep "vtable for Ogre::PCZPlugin"
00046e20 d vtable for Ogre::PCZPlugin

$ nm -C /usr/local/lib/OGRE/Plugin_OctreeZone.so | grep "Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin::OctreeZonePlugin()"
0000c350 t Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin::OctreeZonePlugin()
0000c350 t Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin::OctreeZonePlugin()

$ nm -C /usr/local/lib/OGRE/Plugin_OctreeZone.so | grep "vtable for Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin"
0000fe20 d vtable for Ogre::OctreeZonePlugin
```

So, why linking fails? I am using GNU ld 2.21.53.20110810 and GCC 4.6.1 (everything from Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: You shouldn't need to fight the build system: copy and paste the line that calls the linker and edit it as you want. Try that first and see if removing duplicates helps.

Comment: Those symbols in the OGRE library are marked as *local* (lower case 't'). You might have an issue with how you compiled the library, or you might be trying to use symbols that should not be used from user code. Also, I am not sure whether you should not have `-l` before the .so in the command line...

Answer (score -1):

Order of libraries matters in your linker command: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html

The first thing to do is to put `-o verdox` at the end of the command. I've had that problem before... Then see if there are any errors left.